# Local Passport strategy coupled with Twitter Strategy

Tags: node.js, express, cookies, twitter-oauth, passport.js

Use case: Our team read somewhere that Twitter might pull the auth plug on our service if we get successful so we have a local login strategy (email/password combo) that can serve as a backup for our users if the Twitter login is not working. This means that even if the browser has no cookies stored, the user should still be able to login with a email/password and be authenticated and be given a new cookie, so it's a completely independent login process.

Problem: The problem is that we don't know how to do this right. To my knowledge, Passport will generate a different token each time you login, whatever strategy you use. The problem that we are seeing is that our local-strategy doesn't seem to send back a token/cookie to the browser:

```
passport.use('local-login', new LocalStrategy({

        usernameField: 'email',
        passwordField: 'password',
        passReqToCallback: true // allows us to pass req stream to callback
    },
    function (req, email, password, done) { 

        User.findOne({'email': email}, function (err, user) {

            if (err) {
                done(err);
            }
            else if (!user) {
                done(null, false, req.flash('loginMessage', 'No user found.')); 
            }

            else if (!user.validPassword(password)) {
                done(null, false, req.flash('loginMessage', 'Wrong password.')); // create the loginMessage and save it to session as flashdata
            }
            else {
                done(null, user);
            }

        });

    }));
```

Questions:

A:
I believe that this local login strategy will be independent of the Twitter login strategy, but my question is, do I need to manually send back a cookie using the local-strategy? Because it appears no cookie is being set.

B: We have set session:false, but perhaps we need to set session:true, but honestly, from the docs, I cannot understand what session represents - it appears to be stored in memory on the server which is not what we want in general right?

> After successful authentication, Passport will establish a persistent
>   login session. This is useful for the common scenario of users
>   accessing a web application via a browser. However, in some cases,
>   session support is not necessary. For example, API servers typically
>   require credentials to be supplied with each request. When this is the
>   case, session support can be safely disabled by setting the session
>   option to false.

```
app.get('/api/users/me',
  passport.authenticate('basic', { session: false }),  //<< session is what exactly?
  function(req, res) {
    res.json({ id: req.user.id, username: req.user.username });
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to set session to true as false is  for API-like authentication which requires the client to submit their credentials for each request.

You'll need to have some session store, by default `express-session` uses a memory store which isn't really ideal for production. There are several modules for other session storage options like Redis, Mongo and so on.

Express-session will set a cookie called `connect.sid` which references the session-id in your chosen session store (*read: session information isn't actually stored in the cookie*). You do not need to set the cookie yourself.

An example session setup will look like this (assuming you use Mongodb & Mongoose):

```
var MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')
mongoose.connect(connectionOptions);

app.use(session({
    store: new MongoStore({ mongooseConnection: mongoose.connection })
}));
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: ok thanks yeah we are using cookie-session, but what truly bemuses me is we have session set to false for the twitter-strategy but it doesn't require that we sign in everytime with the twitter

Comment: I'm not sure setting session to false does anything for the twitter strategy. As far as I know after passport-authenticate succeeds the user's session is updated (in your case, the cookie).

Comment: I guess why would there be a difference between the twitter-strategy and the local-strategy WRT session being true or false. Setting session to true or false should have the same effect on both strategies right?

Comment: Just checked and I was right, sessions _are_ required. OAuth 1.0A (the version twitter uses) requires a per-transaction "secret" which is exchanged before the redirect and verified after the redirect.  This secret is stored in the session, hence why sessions are required for any OAuth 1.0-based strategy.